# In my custom React hook, Is it possible to write a function that can return a valid firebase query dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

For my React application, i am attempting to write a custom hook to be used for querying a Firestore database in Firebase.

So far i wrote a hook that uses a pre-defined query which works. What i cannot figure out is how to write a function capable of dynamically generating that query.

Here is what i have so far:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collection, query, where, orderBy, limit } from 'firebase/firestore';

import firebaseConfig from "./firebase.config";

const useQuery = () => {
  
  // NOTE for clarity i am showing initialization of firebase here
  // although this actually happens in another file and is imported.
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

  const firestoreRef = collection(firestore, 'myCollection');
  
  const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState([]);

  const getSnapshot = useCallback(async(queryConstraints:any) => {
  
  // instead of this pre-defined query ...
  const firestoreQuery = query(firestoreRef,
    where('someField', '>=', 'someValue'),
    where('anotherField', '==', 'anotherValue'),
    orderBy('timestamp', 'asc'),
    limit(10)
  );
    
  // ... Id like to be able to take the incoming argument
  // titled 'queryConstraints' of which its value
  // would be an object like this one:
      //  {[{
      //   where: 'someField',
      //   operator: '>=',
      //   value: 'someValue'
      //  },{
      //   where: 'anotherField',
      //   operator: '==',
      //   value: 'anotherValue'
      //  }], 10, 'timestamp', 'asc'}

  // ... and pass it to a function, lets call it 'configAValidQuery' which
  // would parse the object and return a valid query to be applied as follows:

  //  const myQuery = await configAValidQuery(queryConstraints);
  //  const firestoreQuery = query(firestoreRef, myQuery);

    try {
      const docs = await getDocs(firestoreQuery);
      if(docs.empty) {
        // TO DO: HANDLE EMPTY RESULT
      } else {
        setSnapshot(doc.data());
      }
    } catch(error:any) {
      // TO DO: HANDLE ERROR
    }

  }, [firestoreRef]);

  return {
    snapshot,
    getSnapshot
  }
}

export default useQuery;
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to construct what basically amounts to a comma delimited list of function calls dynamically, given that the query constraints consist of the imported firebase methods `where`, `orderBy` and `limit`.

The function i need would look something like the following, although this would obviously not work:

```
const configAValidQuery = useCallback((conditions:any, limit:number, orderBy:string, direction:string) => {
      let query:any;
      if(conditions.length > 0) {
        conditions.map((item:any) => {
          return(query = query.where(item.where, item.operator, item.value))
        });
        query = query.orderBy(orderBy, direction);
        if(limit > 0) {
          query = query.limit(limit);
        }
        return query;
      } else {
        query = query.orderBy(orderBy, direction);
        if(limit > 0) {
          query = query.limit(limit);
        }
        return query;
      }
  },[]);
```

The `firebase/firestore` package does not appear to contain a pre-defined interface or function for this purpose.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this could be nice if you're using typescript

```js
import {
  query,
  where,
  orderBy,
  limit
} from "firebase/firestore";



type Clause = "where" | "limit" | "orderBy";
type Operator = "==" | "!=" | "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">=";

interface WhereArgs {
  column: string;
  operator: Operator;
  value: string | number;
}

interface OrderByArgs {
  column: string;
  order: "asc" | "desc";
}

interface LimitArgs {
  amount: number;
}

type Command =
  | ({ clause: "where" } & WhereArgs)
  | ({ clause: "orderBy" } & OrderByArgs)
  | ({ clause: "limit" } & LimitArgs);

const options = {
  where: (args: WhereArgs) => {
    const { column, operator, value } = args;
    return where(column, operator, value);
  },
  limit: (args: LimitArgs) => {
    const { amount } = args;
    return limit(amount);
  },
  orderBy: (args: OrderByArgs) => {
    const { column, order } = args;
    return orderBy(column, order);
  }
};

const commands: Array<Extract<Command, { clause: Clause }>> = [
  {
    clause: "where",
    column: "anotherField",
    operator: ">=",
    value: "someValue"
  },
  {
    clause: "where",
    column: "anotherField",
    operator: "==",
    value: "anotherValue"
  },
  {
    clause: "limit",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    clause: "orderBy",
    column: "timestamp",
    order: "asc"
  }
];

const constraints = [];

for (const command of commands) {
  const { clause, ...rest } = command;
  constraints.push(options[command.clause](rest as any));
}

query(null as any, ...constraints);
```

here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-jasper-w3fmx?file=/src/index.ts:0-1454) to it

Comment: yes plenty of typescript here, I assume the result of the for loop will give me the array i need and that the loop could live elsewhere inside a function, but can you explain the last line in detail?

Comment: last line is spreading out all the constraints added in the loop into the query function :)

Comment: Yes!! I tested this by incorporating it into my implementation of the hook and it works! I was confused by why you set the first argument of the query function as null, but when i set it appropriately by passing the Firestore reference in as the first argument as i have it in my hook, it works. All of this seems so convoluted and i do wonder if there isnt a solution already provided elsewhere, ie, there are packages available for angular that make it possible to accomplish this goal in just a few lines, but if this works, i am satisfied.

Comment: I have since extended this to include clauses for startAfter and endBefore and this is working flawlessly, thank you, i marked as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstival 'query Constraints' in your question is not an object i don't know what it is.

**I assume this object should look like this:**

```js
const qConstrains = {
        where: [
            { val1: 'fieldName', operator: '>=', val2: 'valueToCompare'},
            { val1: 'anotherfieldName', operator: '>=', val2: 'valueToCompare'}
        ],
        orderBy: { timestamp: 'timestamp', direction: 'asc'},
        limit: 10
    }
```

Well **object above is bad** because query function use `QueryConstraints[]` and it is an array not an object. It is an array witn no objects but functions so all you need to do is make an array of objects so you can save it in database and when using it convert it to an array of functions.

**Here is an example of correct array:**

```js
const qConstrains = [
        { where: 'fieldName', operator: '>=', value: 'valueToCompare'},
        { where: 'anotherfieldName', operator: '>=', value: 'valueToCompare'},
        { orderBy: 'timestamp', direction: 'asc'},
        { limit: 10 }
    ]
```

**Function converting from array of objects to array of functions:**

```js
function convertArrayObjectsToArrayFunctions(queryConstains: any[]) {
    let newQueryConstains: any[] = []
    for(let item of queryConstains) {
        if(item['where']) newQueryConstains.push(where(item.where, item.operator, item.value)) 
        if(item['orderBy']) newQueryConstains.push(orderBy(item.orderBy, item['direction'] ? item.direction : undefined))
        if(item['limit']) newQueryConstains.push(limit(item.limit))
    }
    return newQueryConstains
}
```

**Example of usage:**

```js
// Do not forget to use ... operator when creating a query.
const q = query(collection(db,'posts'),
   ...convertArrayObjectsToArrayFunctions(qConstrains))
```

Home work children! XD function above not contain all of functions there can occur. your job is to add extra if statements for: `'limitToLast' | 'startAt' | 'startAfter' | 'endAt' | 'endBefore'`

**Important:**
If you get an error about indexes just `ctrl + click` on link inside error it will setup indexes for you in firestore.

Comment: `queryConstraints` in my example was just the name i decided to use for the single argument that my function titled 'getSnapshot' accepts. And i was trying to show that the incoming value would be an object, just like your `qConstraints` sample, that i wanted to pass into another function that would convert it into an array of functions in the way that you have demonstrated here. This looks good, i am going to test and will respond, thank you.

Comment: @DevMike No problem. I prefer to use TypeScript over plain JavaScript. You will be more aware of what you are using and able to find faster solutions to your problems.

Comment: @DevMike Yeah test it becouse i just wrote it with no tests.

Comment: not to mention my awful attempt at spelling correctly, hah. Fixing now.

Comment: well, this does not work. convertArrayObjectsToArrayFunctions as you have it, executes each of the methods `where`, `orderBy` and `limit` and the resulting array is returned with those functions already invoked. We are both likely approaching this  the wrong way.

Comment: @DevMike I checked and it works you probably didn't spread function result when created query.

Comment: I see the edits, i will have a look thank you for this! I do like the simplicity here, i also like having everything typed correctly as in the other solution.

Comment: I am seeing a lint error for each of the lines in your for each loop in the shortened example of your `convertArrayObjectsToArrayFunctions ` function: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Comment: only way i see to shorten: `if (item['where']) newQueryConstraints = [ ...newQueryConstraints, where(item.where, item.operator, item.value)];`

Comment: And with that, both answers work as a solution! I wonder if anyone can offer insight into which is more performant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240855/discussion-between-mises-and-devmike).